# No overload for method 'protectDvar' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I have problem "No overload for method 'protectDvar' takes 2 arguments"

Heres snippet of code:

```
private void protectDvar<T>(Entity client, string dvar, T value)
```

Error that's called on:

`protectDvar<string>("r_glow", "1");`

Please help me
Sorry for bad english

Comment: You're function takes 3 arguments, and you're only passing 2.

Comment: the `protectDVar` you have defined takes 3 arguments but you are calling it with 2. Is this your problem?

Comment: are you trying to write an extension method?

Answer (score 2):

remove `Entity client` from parametrs or add this parameter in method call `protectDvar(client, "r_glow", "1");`